# Correct terminology for SharePoint server-side C# aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint server which I run C# code via `.aspx` pages that I edit in SharePoint Designer. I had to enable `PageParserPaths` in order to do this. My main question is what is the correct terminology for this type of setup? I'm hoping to be able to find more accurate solutions to my problems when I google them.